# What does the request to send a resume including a commented list of maximum 3 selected publications mean?

Tags: publications, mathematics, postdocs, cv

I am a PhD student in Mathematics and about to apply for a post-doctoral position. "A resume including a commented list of maximum three selected publications" is requested.

What does the above sentence mean? What is a commented list? I have one publication and one revision recived from a journal recently, I have other 4 reprints communicated. So in total i have 6 papers. So how many of them  should I mention in the resume ?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 [p]reprints communicated"? In case they were not yet published in (or accepted for publication in) a peer-review venue, then you have one peer-reviewed publication, not six. Of course, in that case it makes perfect sense to list your other work as "manuscripts under review" or whatever, but they are not peer-reviewed publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to see the complete instructions to be sure, but I expect they want to know what your main publications are, why they are your main ones, what they are about, and what your contribution was.

Especially the last point is important. Your potential employer doesn't care if you have a paper in the most prestigious journal if your contribution was trivial. They want to see that you can do something on your own. Choose papers that you're the single or main author of, where you can say that it's completely based on your own work.

You can and should still list everything on your CV, but only select and comment on a maximum of three.

Comment: The exact sentence was " send a resume including a commented list of maximum three selected publications". A professor just send me the pdf file of the application form. I am not sure about the weblink of the notification. But I am thankful for your advice in the answer